# Passing the results of wevtutil to a variable or array in git bash

Tags: bash, function, wevtutil

GOAL: As the title suggests i'm needing to pass the results of a function to a variable. Specifically, `LASTLOG() { wevtutil qe "$WINLOG" //c:1 //rd:.ture //f:text }`
This primary command is `wevtutil qe "$WINLOG" //c:1 //rd:.ture //f:text`.

ISSUE: Originally I did the following `LASTLOG=$(wevtutil qe "$WINLOG" //c:1 //rd:.ture //f:text)`, but i've been informed that passing cmds to variables is not best practice so I created a function. `LASTLOG() { wevtutil qe "$WINLOG" //c:1 //rd:.ture //f:text }`--however I cant seem to pass the ouput of the function to a variable for later comparison.

Comment: who said passing commands to variables is not best practice? how have you tried passing the function call (basically a 'command') to a variable?

Comment: I know that the version with the ```var=$(cmd)```, works but b/c this will be public prj I want to use best practice. Idk which bash guide stated it but "functions are for holding commands, variables are for holding data" . I think what I will try is calling the func. the piping the output of the call into a variable--seeing as "cmds" create "data" hopefully my logic is ok.

Comment: so if you have `function LASTLOG { wevtutil qe "$WINLOG" //c:1 //rd:.ture //f:text ;}` in your script, have you tried the variable assignment with `lastlog=$(LASTLOG)` ?

Comment: I have not and will do so, thank you